# Laravel Firebase with Kreait Push notifications

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Exceptions\Handler;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use App\Models\Schedule\OldFCMToken;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\AndroidConfig;

class FirebaseMessagingService
{
    private $messaging;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(storage_path('app/configs/firebase.json'));
        $this->messaging = $factory->createMessaging();
    }

    public function sendNotification(
        string $deviceToken,
        array $notificationData,
        string $link = null,
        string $imageUrl = null,
        string $soundName = null
    ) {
        try {
            $androidConfig = AndroidConfig::fromArray([
                'notification' => [
                    'sound' => $soundName ?? 'default'  // Si aucun son n'est fourni, utilisez 'default' pour le son Android par défaut
                ]
            ]);

            $message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $deviceToken);

            echo $imageUrl . " :1 \n";
            if ($imageUrl) {
                 echo $imageUrl . " :2 \n";
                 $notificationData['image'] = $imageUrl;
            }

            $message = $message->withNotification($notificationData);

            $data = ['key' => 'value'];
            if ($link) {
                $data['link'] = $link;
            }

            $message = $message->withData($data)
                ->withAndroidConfig($androidConfig)
                ->withDefaultSounds();

            $this->messaging->send($message);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
          
            app(Handler::class)->report($th);
        }
    }
}
```

I use this service to send my notifications to my Android app (written in Flutter), but neither the image nor the sound nor the link works when I receive the notification on my phone.

If anyone can help me solve this problem of sound that doesn't work when I receive the notification, images even when included that don't display and links where I want the user to be redirected if there are any.